# Cannot create HTTP POST to ESP8266 server using Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, esp8266

Don't know is it important but this operation is a part of onClickListener method at RecycledView Object. I am trying to send HTTP POST to my esp8266 server.  My phone is connected to ACCESPOINT hosted by ESP8266 where server is setup also.

Using my browser I can create POST request typing URL :

> http://192.168.11.4/register?WiFiSSID=wifissid&WiFiPassword=passssword&FirebaseUserToken=12122

and everything works fine.

When I try do the same using Retrofit, my app is crashing and logs shows :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.lightmeup, PID: 2805
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #4 bootstrap method
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313)
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:492)
    at com.example.lightmeup.Retrofit.RetrofitClient$instance$2.invoke(RetrofitClient.kt:12)
    at com.example.lightmeup.Retrofit.RetrofitClient$instance$2.invoke(RetrofitClient.kt:6)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.example.lightmeup.Retrofit.RetrofitClient.getInstance(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.example.lightmeup.NewDevice.NewDeviceViewHolder$1.onClick(NewDeviceViewHolder.kt:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:87) 
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipLeadingAsciiWhitespace(Util.java:321) 
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder.parse(HttpUrl.java:1313) 
    at okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(HttpUrl.java:917) 
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:492) 
    at com.example.lightmeup.Retrofit.RetrofitClient$instance$2.invoke(RetrofitClient.kt:12) 
    at com.example.lightmeup.Retrofit.RetrofitClient$instance$2.invoke(RetrofitClient.kt:6) 
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74) 
    at com.example.lightmeup.Retrofit.RetrofitClient.getInstance(Unknown Source:7) 
    at com.example.lightmeup.NewDevice.NewDeviceViewHolder$1.onClick(NewDeviceViewHolder.kt:31) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318) 
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

My Retrofit code below :

**RetrofitClient**

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object RetrofitClient {

private const val BASE_URL = "http://192.168.11.4/"

val instance: Api by lazy{
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
}

}
```

**Api**

```
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.Field
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface Api {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register")
fun sendRegisterInfo(
    @Field("WiFiSSID") WiFiSSID:String,
    @Field("WiFiPassword") WiFiPassword:String,
    @Field("FirebaseUserToken") FirebaseUserToken:String
): Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

**NewDeviceViewHolder**

```
class NewDeviceViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

private lateinit var capabilities: String

init {
    view.setOnClickListener {
        WiFiConnector.setContext(view.context)
        WiFiConnector.connect(view.context, view.textView_SSID.text.toString()) //Connecting to ESP8266 AccesPoint 

        var info = RegisterInfo("111222333", "Tajne_Haslo","TOKENnieDOpoznania")

        RetrofitClient.instance.sendRegisterInfo(info.WiFiSSID, info.WiFiPassword, info.FirebaseUserToken)
            .enqueue(object: Callback<ResponseBody>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.context, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                    response: Response<ResponseBody>
                ) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.context, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            })
    }
}


@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
fun bind(newDevice: NewDevice) = with(view) {
    textView_SSID.text = newDevice.SSID
    textView_BSSID.text = newDevice.BSSID
    textView_LEVEL.text = newDevice.LEVEL.toString() + "dB"

}

}
```

**ESP8266 server**

```
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

String ssid = "LightMeUpe:" + WiFi.macAddress();
String password = "";

IPAddress ip(192,168,11,4);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,11,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.println("Configure Acces Point...");
WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
WiFi.softAPConfig(ip,gateway,subnet);
WiFi.softAP(ssid,password);

Serial.print("IP address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
Serial.print("AP SSID: ");
Serial.println(ssid);

server.on("/",handleIndex);
server.on("/register",handleRegister);
server.begin();


Serial.println("HTTP server started");
Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
server.handleClient();
}


void handleIndex() {
server.send(200,"text/plain","OK");
}

void handleRegister() {

String WiFiSSID = server.arg("WiFiSSID");
String WiFiPassword = server.arg("WiFiPassword");
String FirebaseUserToken = server.arg("FirebaseUserToken");

Serial.println(WiFiSSID);
Serial.println(WiFiPassword);
Serial.println(FirebaseUserToken);

server.send(200,"text/plain","Registered");
}
```

Comment: `Using my browser I can create POST request typing URL :`. The browser on your phone? If not try first.

Comment: But your url for the browser is no POST request but a GET request.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException` Catch that exception. Your app will not crash then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this gonna help but can you try this as pointed by other users getting same exception. Try adding this in your `app/build.gradle` might be a compatibility issue with some native code

```
android {
    //.... some other code
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```